# Trouble inserting a date into a MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked at several of the threads that have to do with this issue and still can't figure out what's going wrong with my code.

I'm bring a date field from my form that is in this format "mm-dd-yyyy", when I bring it to my code to update the date of birth field as "yyyy-dd-mm" I use the following

```
$birth=$_POST['dateBorn'];
$dateB = date('Y-d-m',strtotime($birth));
$finaldateB = ($dateB === false) ? '0000-00-00' : date('Y-d-m',strtotime($dateB));
```

When I echo the values of the variables (using a date of birth of 11-23-2012) I see the following values for them birth = 11-23-2012, dateB = 1969-31-12, finaldateB = 1969-31-12

I'm obviously doing something incorrect and haven't been able to locate where

TIA

In order to get things to function, I've at least discovered a work-around that may not be elegant but gives me the results I need for now

```
 $dateB = $birth;
 $dateborn_a=explode("-",$birth);
 $yearborn = $dateborn_a[2];
 $dayborn = $dateborn_a[1];
 $monthborn = $dateborn_a[0];
 $dateOfBirth=$yearborn."-".$monthborn."-".$dayborn;
```

And then use the value in $dateOfBirth to update the table. It's worked for all the records I've tested it on so far.

Comment: What is the type of field for the date in your table? Is it date, datetime, varchar?

Answer (score 5):

```
$dateB = date('Y-d-m',strtotime($birth));
```

here

```
y is for year 
d is for day
m is for month
```

so formate will be  `yyyy-dd-mm`

try

```
$dateB = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($birth));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using Y-d-m instead of Y-m-d. MySQL's date format should be YEAR-MONTH-DAY. Using

```
$dateB = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($birth));
```

should fix it.

Comment: This is aggravating,it's still echoing 1969-12-31--- The field in database is a 'date',

Comment: @Hank What is the value of $dateB?

Comment: Wayne, if I use strtotime($birth) it comes back empty

Comment: Not sure if this matters, the value is being placed into the text field via a javascript popup that puts the date in the format mm-dd-yyyy, and when that value is consistently correct.

Comment: @Hank Make sure that you're using - instead of / when using strtotime

Comment: @Hank mm-dd-yyyy isn't accepted by strtotime. You'll get a FALSE value back.